# JavaScript is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write the following so that I can initiate Game by calling `Game.init()` but I keep getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Game.init is not a function

```js
var Game = function() {
  return {
    init: function(url) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
    },
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  }
}

$(function() {
  Game.init('./file.json');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `Game().init()` wold be a function, `Game` by itself is a function which doesn't have an `init` property.

Comment: Maybe you meant to write the Game code as an iife that executes immediately and returns the inner object.

Comment: @James that's also a possibility. I'm not sure what the intention was here. An IIFE doesn't help much, since there is nothing to close over, really.

Comment: Thanks @James thats exactly what was missing!

Answer (score 1):

As VLAZ pointed out it has to be `Game().init()` or else you can make a immediately invoking function expression

```js
var Game = (function() {
  return {
    init: function(url) {
      console.log('test')
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
    },
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  }
}())

$(function() {
  Game.init('./file.json');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var Game = (function () {
    return {
        init: function (url) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Game is a function not an object

```
$(function () {
    Game().init('./file.json');
});
```

Comment: Functions _are_ objects.